# adding time from 2 cells in 3rd cell =#VALUE error

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to add (Formate) m/d h:mm, with =TODAY() in R26, with 
(Formate) d h:mm in S26......

Formula  '=R26+S26' in cell U26

all I get is #VALUE

Purpose: after entering the d h:mm value to S26, I need U26 to give me the m/d h:mm value, which is the format of the cell.
It's to give me the day and time that I need to attend to something that is expiring and needs to be renewed/reactivated.

I've tried 'S26=(NOW()+S26); S26=NOW()+S26; S26=NOW()+(S26)

anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Excel time values are decimal numbers. If both cells contain real numbers, not text, then your formula should work. The #Value error shows because at least one of the values is text.

The format of a cell is not important when doing calculations. All that matters is the underlying data type.

Change the cell values to be real numbers (formatted as time).

Comment: thank you. from your suggestion, i was able to find a way to get it to work.

Comment: if that solved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]